# How to replace ALL django "Status Code Exception" templates

Tags: django, response, http-status-codes

Any Status Code exceptions like 404, 403, 405, 500, CSRF and more return their own "Django" specific templates, a few are HTML.

handler403, handler404, and handler500 exist and can be easily overridden, but there are a lot of these "hidden" Django templates that are being returned upon error, an example is 405 (method does not exist) or CSRF (if no CSRF token is in the request) and probably many more.

Is it possible to have a custom view (such as just a generic 404 return) for ALL of these "hidden" Django HTML templates?

Comment: Have your read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847441/django-exception-handling-best-practice-and-sending-customized-error-message

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views, a pretty limited set.

Comment: Yes I mention that specifically in the OP